# Is Django test Client can work with different domains?

Tags: python, django, testing

Can i use Client for testing functional with, for example, different regional domains of project?

I try:

```
response = client.post(reverse('uri'), data={}, HTTP_HOST='domain1')
response = client.post(reverse('uri'), data={}, HTTP_HOST='domain2')
```

And i expected, that Client get different cookies for different domains, but in fact client get single cookie.

Is any way to get different cookies in this case? Or only way use CI with silenium?

Comment: The test client does not use real HTTP, it processes the request internally. Also domains are usually served by a webserver before Django. So, can you explain your usecase and domain implementation?

Comment: I need see that same real client (anonymous) on different domains is same anonymous. So i add in project django-xsession and try write test that confirm that problem solved. But at this moment even with disabled django-xsession i can't show that problem exists at all, because Client don't get second cookie after request to second domain.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do has left the area of unittests and it is already an end to end or behavior test. The normal test client is not made for this. You might want to have a look at the live test server: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase

Comment: Thanks, I almost thought so, but I was just not sure.